# Drop down list in struts2

Tags: struts2

How to populate ddropdown list in a web page in struts2 from database. The items of the drop down will be taken from database.

Comment: Some more details please... You can give an example of the input and desired output. What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: Im creating a webpage in which i have to select the name of the country. The country names cannot be hard coaded because it changes frequently and hence the items in the dropdown list will be populated from the database containing the names of the country.

Comment: Ok. Could you please show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating list in struts2, we can use implement Preparable.

```
public class CountryListAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

 private List<String> country;
 getters and setters 

 public String prepareCountryList() throws Exception{

  country=new ArrayList<String>();
  country=fill country from database;

 }

 public String countryList() throws Exception{
  return SUCCESS;
 }

}
```

For jsp, use:

```
<s:select label="Select Country"
   name="country"
   headerValue="Select Country"
   list="%{country}"
/>
```

Preparable interface will call prepareCountryList method before calling countryList and jsp will be prepopulated. You can populate as many drop down list using single method in struts2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a List in you action class with getters and setters and all you have to do is to populate the list inside your Action's execute method.

### Action Class

```
public class MyListAction extends ActionSupport{

  private List<String> country;
  getters and setters 

  public String execute() throws Exception{

    country=new ArrayList<String>();
    countr=fill country from database;
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

Now all you need to have a S2 select tag with following entry

```
<s:select label="Select Country"
       name="country"
       headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Country"
       list="%{country}"

/>
```

here *list* is an Iterable source to populate from. If the list is a Map (key, value), the Map key will become the option 'value' parameter and the Map value will become the option body.
So  `list=%{country}` will be evaluated by OGNL as getCountry() method in your action class and will fetch the required list from value-stack to populate the drop down

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
   <s:select name="someName" id="someId" 
list="someMap_or_List" onchange="someFunction();"/>
```

here someMap_or_List is the List or Map that you can use to populate your Drop Down List.