# populate struts2 drop down list from an arrray list

Tags: drop-down-menu, struts2, arraylist, populate

Actually several links are there, describing how to populate select tag in struts2 using arraylist.[Drop down list in struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581684/drop-down-list-in-struts2). But i didnt get it. Error I got is

**tag 'select', field 'list', name 'role': The requested list key '%{oList}' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]**

(My list name is oList,which is already filled from action class from database)

> List oList=new ArrayList();

Please help me to clear my error. I tried several. Sorry if i do any mistake.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19335468/1700321.

Comment: Do you have getter and setters defined for the oList in Action class?

Comment: I think you suggest me to check my case.i changed my variable to 'List olist=new ArrayList();'. But i get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be setters and getters for your list (in your case "oList") for corresponding action class when assigning to struts select tag.